# Ensure that Gunicorn restarts when the old process dies

Tags: debian-wheezy, django

A server process can die for example by a small error in the coding or from other reasons.

Has anybody experience with Gunicorn (+Django) and how solid it runs? Is there an easy way to ensure that the process is restarted when it dies of some reason?

BTW: I am running Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by myself:

Gunicorn can be controlled by [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). An example configuration can be found in the Gunicorn documentation.